# How to increase the gap between text and underlining in CSS

Tags: css, underline

Using CSS, when text has `text-decoration:underline` applied,  is it possible to increase the distance between the text and the underline?

Comment: This is not exactly what you were asking for, but it was an interesting read on the subject: [CSS Design: Custom Underlines](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/customunderlines/)

Comment: The distance is determined by a font used. Try web-safe fonts.

Comment: CSS3 has a lot of new text-decoration properties these days. Please check out alligator.io/css/text-decoration Example: `text-underline-position: under;` and `text-decoration-skip: ink;` Please note that this is probably not backward compatible with older browsers.

Comment: Another [good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8037837/3452348)

Comment: Vote for `text-underline-offset` here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=785230&q=text-underline-offset&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: Just add `text-underline-position: under;`

Comment: `text-underline-offset`  now works.

Answer (score 477, accepted):

No, but you could go with something like `border-bottom: 1px solid #000` and `padding-bottom: 3px`.

If you want the same color of the "underline" (which in my example is a border), you just leave out the color declaration, i.e. `border-bottom-width: 1px` and `border-bottom-style: solid`.

For multiline, you can wrap you multiline texts in a span inside the element. E.g. `<a href="#"><span>insert multiline texts here</span></a>` then just add `border-bottom` and `padding` on the `<span>` - [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Aishaterr/vrpb2ey7/1)

Comment: My only problem with this trick is when I am using line-height equal to the div height and then vertical-align: middle; to get it centered, then i can't use this trick because then the underline ends up below the div.

Comment: @deweydb: How about adding the padding-bottom to the container div as well? http://jsfiddle.net/dYfjc/1/

Comment: +1 I didn't know about leaving off the color property to inherit the font's color - that'll save much sweat and tears in future!

Comment: 5 years later this is still useful! +1 for a sweet workaround

Comment: border-bottom sometimes expands beyond the width of the text. you can add display: inline-block to your anchor element to fix this.

Comment: I am pretty not sure why this answer has so many upvotes. This doesn't completely work with multiline texts.

Comment: It also works badly if you already have a padding in the tag and has no freedom to modify it.

Comment: what if text is multiline?

Comment: The text-shadow is not applied to the border, which is an issue for me.

Comment: For multiline, you can wrap you multiline texts in a span inside the element. E.g. `<a href="#"><span>insert multiline texts here</span></a>` then just add border-bottom and padding on the `<span>`. https://jsfiddle.net/Aishaterr/vrpb2ey7/1/

Comment: @Aishaterr very nice, I think your code is much prettier than the others. If you wish, you could edit this answer to include your exact comment (the jsfiddle helps a lot when conveying people :))

Comment: To look more like under line, we can add padding-left:2px and padding-right:2px So that line get extra width under the text. Thanks to the author for solution.

Answer (score 369):

**Update 2021:**
`text-underline-offset` now works in almost all major and newest versions of browsers (IE11 is a no-go): https://caniuse.com/?search=text-underline-offset

**Update 2019:** The CSS Working Group has published a draft for [text decoration level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-decor-4/) which would add a new property [`text-underline-offset`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-decor-4/#underline-offset) (as well as [`text-decoration-thickness`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-decor-4/#text-decoration-width-property)) to allow control over the exact placement of an underline. As of this writing, it's an early-stage draft and has not been implemented by any browser, but it looks like it will eventually make the technique below obsolete.

**Original answer below.**

---

The problem with using `border-bottom` directly is that even with `padding-bottom: 0`, the underline tends to be too far *away* from the text to look good. So we still don't have complete control.

One solution that gives you pixel accuracy is to use the `:after` pseudo element:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
}
a:after {
    content: '';

    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 1px;

    border-width: 0 0 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

By changing the `bottom` property (negative numbers are fine) you can position the underline exactly where you want it.

One problem with this technique to beware is that it behaves a bit weird with line wraps.

Comment: This won't work for my particular issue, but this is a fantastic trick. +1

Comment: Good work around, but this will not work for anchors that span multiple lines

Comment: @last-child This one is better than underline, but with text wrap this would not work for every line

Comment: One problem is that a border-bottom and underlining are two different things. For instance should part of the text extend below the underline. If you style a-tags as buttons, you have no freedom of using border-bottom as underlining.

Comment: Add z-index:-1 for bring border under the text

Comment: Imagine telling someone who is either new to web development, a graphic designer, an average user, or your mom, that this is what's required to add some controlled space between text and it's underline and they will wonder what you're doing with your life.

Comment: I was able to control the distance of the border by using `line-height`.  It was on a `<h3>` so I used `inline-block` as well

Comment: Thanks for the update. As of August 2020, `text-underline-offset` works beautifully in Safari and Firefox. (Chrome didn't get the memo apparently.)

Comment: `text-underline-offset` has been recently added to Chrome and Edge. What a time to be alive!

Answer (score 129):

You can use this `text-underline-position: under`

See here for more detail: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-underline-position/

See also [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-position#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Thanks! If you are trying to do a dashed underline and see that it is drawn without space between the bottom of the text and the line, then this fixes the issue.

Comment: This is the correct answer for modern browsers without any workaround.

Comment: It does not work in Firefox, not even with vendor-prefix - but it IS in a W3C spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#text-underline-position-property. Other relevant resource: https://www.quackit.com/css/css3/properties/css_text-underline-position.cfm

Comment: Great find! I look at this as that we should use it now until the other browsers catch up on the spec. For those who don't have it, they'll just get a less than desirable appearance, but not too terribly bad.

Comment: This is the real answer. Using `borders` will only work on one-lines, you will see the problem with multilines.

Comment: As of this moment, this only really works in the chrome browser, and is not a solution for other browsers.

Comment: Unfortunately only Chrome supports this https://caniuse.com/#search=text-underline-position

Comment: Well, as of the date of this comment, I see this **works in Firefox** too.

Comment: Chrome is having issues rendering this in some instances *for me*. Looks like it's generally poorly tested. Yes it works initially, but with additional hover styling, the underline will sometimes get cut in half or disappear completely, seemingly undeterministically.

Comment: Perfect, Other answers are far too cumbersome.This should be marked as correct answer.

Answer (score 59):

Use

```
{
   text-decoration: underline;
   text-underline-offset: 2px;
}

Here, text-underline-offset: 2px;  is used to define the distance of the underline from the text, where "2px" is the distance.

Note: text-underline-offset: 2px;  can only be used after 
                  text-decoration: underline;

You can also change the thickness of underline by writing
                   text-decoration: underline 5px;
where "5px" is the thickness.
```

Refer this link for further query: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-offset

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it improves on the many other upvoted answers this question has already, so that it is useful to other users with similar issues

Comment: There's no chrome support for this. https://caniuse.com/?search=text-underline-offset

Comment: errrr yes - as explanation .... `text-underline-offset: 2px` sets the text underline to an offset of 2px... in case someone doesn't understand. Chrome supports as well now.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it works well even in 2022. It is currently supported by Chrome, Edge, Opera.

Answer (score 33):

Here is what works well for me.

```html
<style type="text/css">
  #underline-gap {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-underline-position: under;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <h1 id="underline-gap"><a href="https://Google.com">Google</a></h1>
</body>
```

Comment: It is important to note that `text-underline-position` is not supported under Firefox as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-position#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Very interesting. Great callout. Thank you!

Comment: Supported in Firefox starting from 74, as per the same link.

Answer (score 12):

Getting into the details of the visual style of `text-decoration:underline` is pretty much futile, so you're going to have to go with some kind of hack the removes `text-decoration:underline` and replaces it with something else until a magical far-distant future version of CSS gives us more control.

This worked for me:

```css
   a {
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        180deg, rgba(0,0,0,0),
        rgba(0,0,0,0) 81%, 
        #222222 81.1%,
        #222222 85%,
        rgba(0,0,0,0) 85.1%,
        rgba(0,0,0,0)
    );
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a> dolor sit amet, <a href="#">consetetur sadipscing</a> elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <a href="#">invidunt ut labore.</a>
```

- Adjust the % values (81% and 85%) to change how far the line is from the text
- Adjust the difference between the two % values to change the line thickness
- adjust the color values (#222222) to change the underline color
- works with multiple line inline elements
- works with any background

Here's a version with all the proprietary properties for some backwards compatibility:

```
a {     
    /* This code generated from: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 81%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 81.1%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 85%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 85.1%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(81%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(81.1%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(85%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(85.1%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 81%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 81.1%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 85%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 85.1%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 81%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 81.1%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 85%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 85.1%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 81%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 81.1%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 85%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 85.1%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 81%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 81.1%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 85%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 85.1%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* W3C */

    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**Update: SASSY version**

I made a scss mixin for this. If you don't use SASS, the regular version above still works great...

```
@mixin fake-underline($color: #666, $top: 84%, $bottom: 90%) {
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        180deg, rgba(0,0,0,0),
        rgba(0,0,0,0) $top,
        $color $top + 0.1%,
        $color $bottom,
        rgba(0,0,0,0) $bottom + 0.1%,
        rgba(0,0,0,0)
    );
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

then use it like so:

```
$blue = #0054a6;
a {
    color: $blue;
    @include fake-underline(lighten($blue,20%));
}
a.thick {
    color: $blue;
    @include fake-underline(lighten($blue,40%), 86%, 99%);
}
```

**Update 2: Descenders Tip**

If you have a solid background color, try adding a thin `text-stroke` or `text-shadow` in the same color as your background to make the descenders look nice.

**Credit**

This is simplified version of the technique I originally found at https://eager.io/app/smartunderline, but the article has since been taken down.

Comment: Unfortunately the eager.io link doesn't work anymore. Do you recall what was the hack to make descenders look nicer?

Comment: @Kano -  I believe it was using text-shadow in the same color as a solid background.

Comment: Also, with the technique above you can set the color of the underline different from the text, so sometimes I set it to be lighter than the text, which makes collisions with the descenders less of a problem for readability.

Answer (score 12):

There is a easy very answer for this:

```
text-decoration: underline;
text-underline-offset: 3px;
```

`text-underline-offset` is css it's own method.
Here is more about [`text-underline-offset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-offset)

Answer (score 7):

I know it's an old question, but for single line text setting `display: inline-block` and then setting the `height` has worked well for me to control the distance between a border and the text.

Comment: I didn't need to set the height. I just wrapped it in another div and as I wanted it to be centered I just set the text-align on the out div.

Answer (score 6):

@last-child's answer is a great answer!

However, adding a border to my H2 produced an underline longer than the text.

If you're dynamically writing your CSS, or if like me you're lucky and know what the text will be, you can do the following:

1. change the `content` to something the right length (ie the same
2. text) set the font color to `transparent` (or `rgba(0,0,0,0)` )

to underline `<h2>Processing</h2>` (for example),
change last-child's code to be:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
}
a:after {
    content: 'Processing';
    color: transparent;

    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 1px;

    border-width: 0 0 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: H2s are block elements which might explain why the underline was longer than the text. Maybe `display: inline-block` would fix it. Replacing the text with `content` looks like a hack that could break in many ways.

Answer (score 3):

See my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2j5w3pe3/).

You would need to use the border width property and the padding property. I added some animation to make it look cooler:

```css
body{
  background-color:lightgreen;
}
a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:green;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

a:hover{
  color:darkblue;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
  padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<a href='#' >Somewhere ... over the rainbow (lalala)</a> , blue birds, fly... (tweet tweet!), and I wonder (hmm) about what a <i><a href="#">what a wonder-ful world!</a> World!</i>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want:

- multiline
- dotted
- with custom bottom padding
- without wrappers

underline, you can use *1 pixel height* background image with `repeat-x` and `100% 100%` position:

```
display: inline;
background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAABCAYAAAD0In+KAAAAEUlEQVQIW2M0Lvz//2w/IyMAFJoEAis2CPEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=') repeat-x 100% 100%;
```

You can replace the second `100%` by something else like `px` or `em` to adjust the vertical position of the underline. Also you can use `calc` if you want to add vertical padding, e.g.:

```
padding-bottom: 5px;
background-position-y: calc(100% - 5px);
```

Of course you can also make your own base64 png pattern with another color, height and design, e.g. here: http://www.patternify.com/ - just set square width & height at 2x1.

*Source of inspiration: http://alistapart.com/article/customunderlines*

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `text-decoration: underline;`, then you can add space between underline and text by using `text-underline-position: under;`

For more The text-underline-position properties, you can have look [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-underline-position/)

Answer (score 1):

This is what i use:

html:

```
<h6><span class="horizontal-line">GET IN</span> TOUCH</h6>
```

css:

```
.horizontal-line { border-bottom: 2px solid  #FF0000; padding-bottom: 5px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative for multiline texts or links, you can wrap your texts in a span inside a block element.

```
<a href="#">
    <span>insert multiline texts here</span>
</a>
```

then you can just add border-bottom and padding on the `<span>`.

```
a {
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
}

span {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0099d3;
  line-height: 48px;
}
```

You may refer to this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/Aishaterr/vrpb2ey7/2/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to Do it using the U (Underline Tag)

```
u {
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
}
u:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 1px;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}


<a href="" style="text-decoration:none">
    <div style="text-align: right; color: Red;">
        <u> Shop Now</u>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I use:

```
<span style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"> Enter text here </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some great solutions here but each one has some issues. The text-underline-offset is different for each browser. The answer by squarecandy also works, however is a little complicated. Using the border-bottom changes the layout of the text and will shift things over.

One solution for adding a custom underline is to make the underline a background image, that is sized relevant to the text size.

```
    a {
        /* Change the source image to account for changes to the text colour. It should be a single column. */
        background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw__EDITED_OUT___0KGgYII=);
        /*background-image: url('underlineImage.png');*/
        background-size: 1px 1.1em;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        display: inline;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

As the text increases, the position remains relative to the text size. With this, you can have any underline image you want such as "a row of stars", or just a line.

The example above does not include the full base64 information to create the effect. This works great across all the browsers since it's a fundamental thing and is pretty compatible with older browsers.

```
<a href="#">This _____ is the link</a>
```

If the background image is a png with transparency, it works great on top of other elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using :

```
text-underline-position: under;

text-underline-offset: {value(px)};
```

This property will **shift the underline**, that's below your link **by the value of offset** that you provided.

For more references, visit:
[text-underline-offest | developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-offset)