# space between text and underline

Tags: html, css, underline

i am using `text-decoration:underline;` but text and underline are touching each other.can i increase space between text and underline?

[image]
  this one. i want to make space between text and underline.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Either use a different font or use a `border-bottom` instead so that you can control the space with `padding-bottom`.

Comment: Instructions how to do this on  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734618/css-underline-possible-to-increase-gap.

Comment: If you have trouble with your border-bottom expanding beyond the width of the text, add `display: inline-block`

Comment: Also related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734618/css-underline-possible-to-increase-gap

Comment: Doesn't work for multi-line links :(

Comment: Underlining multi-line links sounds awful anyway...

Comment: The distance is determined by a font used. Try web-safe fonts.

Answer (score 26):

I had same issue then i used :

```
.underline_text {
      border-bottom: solid 2px #000000;
      display: inline;
      padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```