# Spacing between text and underline

Tags: html, css, underline

I am looking for a way to enlarge the distance between the text and underline on my pages. i use mainly CSS but i had to use  tags as well, basicly my question considers both cases. is there a way to change this spacing? the code is pretty simple:

```
.title_span {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: grey;
}
```

my other posibility is try somehow use background for the span using 1px picture and repeat against X axis i am looking for cleaner solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734618/css-underline-possible-to-increase-gap

Comment: possible duplicate of [space between text and underline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085394/space-between-text-and-underline)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not without tricks, no. One simple solution is to wrap the text in another span and give that a bottom border.

```css
.title_span {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: grey;
}

.underline {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  border-bottom: grey 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<span class="underline">
  <span class="title_span">title of something</span>
</span>
```

Comment: There is no need for the extra wrapper, you can transfer the border properties directly inside the .title_span : http://jsfiddle.net/m9RQ9/2/

Comment: when i apply padding-left to the title_span the underline remains at initial position. it should move along the text. @Aaron Digulla

Comment: @Tayyab_Hussain: Padding is inside the box. Try margin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this isn't possible per se, but what you can do is apply a `border-bottom` as an alternative to `background-image`

Answer (score 0):

spacing between text and underline its No, but you could go with something like `border-bottom: 1px solid #000` and `padding-bottom: 3px`.

edit: if you want the same color of the "underline" (which in my example is a border), you just leave out the color declaration, i.e. `border-bottom-width: 1px` and `border-bottom-style: solid`.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever feel that your line is too close, we actually have a [`text-underline-offset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-offset) feature that allows you to control the distance between the underline and the text.

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana;
}

span {
  color: #FF0033;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-decoration: #FF0033 underline 0.2rem;
  text-decoration-style: double;  /* default is solid */
  text-underline-offset: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<span>PayPayカード</span>
```