# How make text-decoration: underline with 2px padding?

Tags: html, css

I like an obedient frotend developer must create underline with 2px padding instead of 1px by default. Is exist simple solution for this?

PS Yeahh guys, I know about div with black backgrond color and 1px * Npx and position: relative, but It's so slowly...

Comment: CSS3 has a lot of new text-decoration properties these days. Please check out https://alligator.io/css/text-decoration/ Example: ´text-decoration-position: under;´ and ´text-decoration-skip: ink;´ Please note that this is probably not backward compatible with older browsers.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You could wrap the text in a `span` and give it a `border-bottom` with `padding-bottom:2px;`.

Like so

```
span{
    display:inline-block;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    padding-bottom:2px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uSMGU/

Comment: Using this solution you can't make padding 2px, just 3 or more ;-(

Comment: Not sure what you mean @NiLL?  Can you be more specific about what you cannot do?

Comment: In CSS exist property, - text-decoration:underline. It's draw line below text with padding 1px. I need same effect, but with 2px.

Comment: My understanding is you can't change the default on `text-decoration`. That's why you need a workaround like what I suggested.

Comment: Hi, how does it work for `<li>` elements? When I change it to `<li>` then the whole line is underlined. I want to underline only the text displayed between the `<li></li>` tags. And, also, I have to remove the `display` setting, otherwise the bullets don't appear.

Answer (score 64):

For cross-browsing it is better to use `text-underline-offset` over the `text-underline-position`, because `text-underline-position` isn't supported by [iOS Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-position#browser_compatibility)

So use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63607426/1894907

```
#line{
    text-decoration-line: underline;
    text-underline-offset: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

A great way to do this without adding and extra spans and having more control is using the `:after` selector.

Useful especially for navigation menus:

```
.active a:after {
    content: '';
    height: 1px;
    background: black; 
    display:block;
}
```

If you want more or less space between the text and the underline, add a `margin-top`.

If you want a thicker underline, add more `height`:

```
.active a:after {
    content: '';
    height: 2px;
    background: black; 
    display:block;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Comment: This is great, except I am noticing it ruins the horizontally centered alignment with flexbox because it adds height to the item.

Comment: I am adding an answer in here with my solution that fixes the horizontal alignment issue.

Answer (score 14):

```css
#line{
    text-decoration-line: underline;
    text-underline-offset: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="line">
Text with line
</div>
```

---

just use

```
{
    text-decoration-line: underline;
    text-underline-offset: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it improves on the many other upvoted answers this question has already, so that it is useful to other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 13):

Simply use:

```
text-decoration: underline;
text-underline-position: under;
```

[image]

Comment: text-underline-position is not supported by OS Safari: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-position#browser_compatibility 
for cross-browsing it is better to use text-underline-offset

Answer (score 7):

how about using `border-bottom:1px; padding:what-you-likepx`

Answer (score 2):

```
.my-underlined-text {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-underline-offset: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waLYJr) is my solution...

**HTML**

```
<p>hola dasf  hola dasdsaddasds dsadasdd<span></span></p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
}
a:hover {
    color: blue;
}
p span {
    display:block;
    border-bottom:3px solid black;
    width: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used @jake's solution, but it gave me trouble with the horizontal alignment.

My nav links are flex row, center aligned and his solution caused the element to shift upwards in order to stay horizontally center-aligned.

I fixed it by doing this:

```
a.nav_link-active {
  color: $e1-red;
  margin-top: 3.7rem;
}
a.nav_link-active:visited {
  color: $e1-red;
}
a.nav_link-active:after {
  content: '';
  margin-top: 3.3rem;      // margin and height should
  height: 0.4rem;          // add up to active link margin
  background: $e1-red;
  display: block;
}
```

> This will maintain the horizontal alignment for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a bit of a hack using ::after elements, and positioning them manually. This does mean that you have to maintain the `content` attribute of the after element but you could make this easier by using a data attribute in the html tag and referring to it. See the example below -

```css
span:after {
    font-size: 1rem;
    position: absolute;
    content: 'Hello there..';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    white-space: pre;
    text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
    text-decoration-line: underline;
    left: 0px;
    top: 10px;
    color: white;
    z-index: -1;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-style: wavy;
    text-decoration-color: black;
}

span {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<span>Hello there</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.yourElement{
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
line-height: 2;
}
```