# Underline links in navbar in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, navbar, underline

I have the underlining part down. I am just trying to get the underline itself further away from the text. Also, this is occurs when I hover, which I want.

For example:

Home

---

Something like that.

My code so far:

`#menu a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #252525;
    text-decoration:underline;
}`

If anymore information is necessary, please let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [css, underline, possible to increase gap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734618/css-underline-possible-to-increase-gap)

Comment: For this you'll need `padding-bottom` and a `border-bottom`, as underlines are text-markup and can't be modified.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `border-bottom` instead of `underline` so you can use padding to manipulate the space between your link and the underline like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="menu">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#menu a {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #252525;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: transparent solid 1px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
#menu a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #252525;
    border-bottom: red solid 1px;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle with above code: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/39/