# Styling <u> tags

Tags: html, css

I have already visited this:[How to increase the gap between text and underlining in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734618/how-to-increase-the-gap-between-text-and-underlining-in-css) but my approach uses  tags. The OP in the above question uses a css `text-decoration:underline` the approaches provided there are different

I have a heading which is underlined in my webpage.

```
<h1><u>Hello</u></h1>
```

But the gap between the text and the underline is small so I tried this:

```
u
{
   padding-top:10px;
}
```

and this:

```
u
{
   margin-top:10px;
}
```

But the gap between the text and the underline is still the same. Any idea how I can increase the gap?

Comment: You have to know that padding makes a space between your element and whats inside it (in your case the text), margin makes space between your element and the parent element. so there is no way it will change your text underline

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734618/how-to-increase-the-gap-between-text-and-underlining-in-css see the answers here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this solution:

```css
u {
  padding-bottom:10px;
  text-decoration:none;
  border-bottom:3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<h1><u>Hello</u></h1>
```

The problem of your way of finding the solution is that the `u` element is using `text-decoration` for the bottom border. This border can not be moved because it is on the text. The solution is to remove the text-decoration for this and add a own border at bottom. Now you can increase the space between the content of `h1` and the border with `padding-bottom`.

If you want to use the `u` element on other elements normaly you have to write `h1 u` on your CSS.

Comment: wow, thanks a lot.exactly what i wanted. btw can tell me how you got your profile picture , looks cool

Comment: :D - sry, i don't know the service anymore

Answer (score 4):

The `<u>` tag has been deprecated in HTML 4 and XHTML 1, but it has been re-introduced in HTML5 with other semantics.

If you want to underline the text, you could create a wrap element like this:

```
<h1><span class="underline"><span>Hello</span></span></h1>

span.underline{
padding-bottom:3px;
border-bottom:3px solid black;
}
```

You could increase the gap between the text and the underline by changing the `padding-bottom`

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1><a>Hello</a></h1>

a
{
 vertical-align: top;
 border-bottom-width: 2px;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding-bottom: 2px; //You can adjust the distance here.
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/74vn0shc/