# Adjust distance between underline and text using css

Tags: css

I want to add some space between the text and the underline. But when I try to add some border on the bottom it occupies the 100% width of my resolution.
So it looks like this:

[image]

Here's my css:

```
h1 { 
    font-size: 24pt;
    color: #279839;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #279839;
}
```

My page is multilingual so the border bottom should be the same width of the text.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increase the gap between text and underlining in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734618/how-to-increase-the-gap-between-text-and-underlining-in-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to wrap that by some other tag then use `transform` to align `h1` tag at `center` of page and change it's `display` to `inline-block` this applies to only `one h1 tag`,

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 24pt;
  color: #279839;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #279839;
  display: inline-block; /*Add this*/
  left: 50%; /*Add this*/
  transform: translate(-50%, 0); /*Add this*/
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks. I think it is much better without span because I have a lot of headers on my page. :)

Comment: @Jerielle As you added it occupies 100% width of resolution that's because your element is display as block. Welcome :-) Hopefully they all consist of a parent div around it.

Comment: Thanks again. I am really poor when it comes to css. :)

Comment: @Jerielle It's okay :-), must be good in other language in which I'm not :-)

Answer (score 3):

text-underline-offset

```html
<h1 style="text-decoration:underline; text-underline-offset:.25em;">text</h1>
```

Comment: Consider making this a *code snippet*.

Answer (score 2):

You could add `display: inline-block;` to the `<h1>` or you add a `inline` element (like a `span`) inside the `h1` ...

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 span { 
    font-size: 24pt;
    color: #279839;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #279839;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>hello</span></h1>
<h1><span>hello world</span></h1>
<h1><span>hello world and univers</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put a span tag inside the h1

```
<h1 class="the-h1"><span class="the-span">商品</span></h1>
```

the css

```
.the-h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.the-span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24pt;
  color: #279839;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #279839;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Step1: You need to make H1 display:inline-block; so that the border remain according to the width of text instead of window width.

Step2: In Order to provide space you can use css pseudo element

```
h1 { 
font-size: 24pt;
color: #279839;
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
padding-bottom: 5px;
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
margin: 0 0 10px;
}
h1:after {
content:'';
position: absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
height:1px;
background: #279839;
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `h1` tag is a block element by default, so it makes sense that the `border-bottom` goes through the whole width. You would need to change the `display` property of your headline to achieve the wished result.

```
h1 { 
    display: inline-block; /* most solid one; best choice */
    display: initial;      /* most safe one can easily be overwritten */
    display: inline-flex;  /* could be useful if people using flex-grids */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h1 { 
    display:Block;
    width: 25%
    position:relative;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    font-size: 24pt;
    color: #279839;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #279839;
}
```